# Trying to count per month for 2000 , but get an error "ORA-00904: "MONTH": invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS PerMonth
FROM NAS_CUSTOMER 
WHERE YEAR(CUST_BIRTH) = '2000' 
GROUP BY MONTH(CUST_BIRTH)
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle doesn't have a `MONTH()` function.  You can use `EXTRACT()`:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CUST_BIRTH), COUNT(*) AS PerMonth
FROM NAS_CUSTOMER
WHERE CUST_BIRTH >= DATE '2000-01-01' AND
      CUST_BIRTH < DATE '2001-01-01'
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CUST_BIRTH);
```

Similarly for `YEAR()`, but I replaced that with explicit date comparisons.

Comment: That’s very thoughtful of you.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the TO_CHAR() function.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CUST_BIRTH,'mm'),COUNT(*) AS PerMonth
FROM NAS_CUSTOMER 
WHERE TO_CHAR(CUST_BIRTH,'yyyy') = '2000' 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(CUST_BIRTH,'mm')
```